# PHP DateTime Calculation not including last day

Tags: php, date

I am puzzled by a problem i am experiencing right now.

```
$start = strtotime("2013-08-09 11:00 PM");
$end = strtotime("2013-08-11 11:00 PM");
```

I am trying to calculate the difference between the date and time.

```
$numOfDays = ceil(($end - $start) / 86400);  // 86400 seconds in one day
```

What this outputs is **2** and what i am expecting is **3**.

To me, it seems as though its leaving out the last day from the date?

```
$numOfDays = ceil(($end - $start + 1) / 86400);  // 86400 seconds in one day
```

Also, if i add one second to either the start or end date then i start getting the result i need but i'm not sure if this is the right fix, and what actually is causing this behavior?

Comment: But there aren't 86400 seconds in a date all year round (in most countries). What happens when the clocks switch to daylight savings, and then back again?

Comment: Any chance of accepting an answer or letting us know if you need more help?

Comment: Sorry, and Done. I felt like deleting this question as the whole problem was my understanding of the date&time. I actually was looking to include the first and last date into the calculation, i had to make a workaround for that but this question at least opened my eyes. P.S:- I +voted yours already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math is wrong.  There are two days between your dates.

> ```
> Day 1: 2013-08-09 11:00 PM - 2013-08-10 11:00 PM
> Day 2: 2013-08-10 11:00 PM - 2013-08-11 11:00 PM
> ```

There is a 48 hour difference in your dates, which is 2 days.

**UDATE**

To count the entire day, do not include the time.  When you get the timestamp it will be set for 12:00:00AM.  Then for the end date add 1 day.  Again without the time in the string, it will be 12:00:00AM which would give you the difference of 3 days that you are looking for.

> ```
> Day 1: 2013-08-09 12:00 AM - 2013-08-10 12:00 AM
> Day 2: 2013-08-10 12:00 AM - 2013-08-11 12:00 AM
> Day 3: 2013-08-11 12:00 AM - 2013-08-12 12:00 AM
> ```

Comment: Thanks, i guess so. But what i want to accomplish is to count the first date as "whole". "9" Day 1, "10" Day 2 and "11" Day 3.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between those two dates *is* 2 days... From the 9th to the 10th is the first day, from the 10th to the 11th is the second day, 48 hours between the two time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

`2` is the correct result:

from 2013-08-09 11:00 PM to 2013-08-10 11:00 PM is 24 hours
from 2013-08-10 11:00 PM to 2013-08-11 11:00 PM is 24 hours
24h + 24h = 48h
48h = 2 days